# Problematic low quality question

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, low-quality-posts, review

From Review-beta I edited a low quality question where it looked like the question was in the title and only completely understood by viewing the tags too. I did notice it was an old question.

On looking later I saw there was an accepted answer that referred to the OP's code.

So looking at the edits the OP came and deleted all but the last line of their question about a month after the accepted answer was provided.

I think we should revert their (and hence my) edit, otherwise the answers don't make much sense, but I'll let someone else decide to do that.

This also suggests older answered questions may not be relevant for low quality questions.

The question: [trying to show the two graphs on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6791311/256431)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was vandalism for essentially the entirety of the post to be removed.  I have since rolled back to before that edit.  You should feel free to do the same should you see something like this in the future.  If it was someone other than the OP, or if the user was vandalizing lots of posts in that manor then I would consider flagging for moderator attention, but in a case like this I'd say that just rolling back is sufficient.  The question is not particularly good though, and it could use a fair bit of re-work if you want to fix up the original spelling/grammar/formatting/wording.

Comment: Yeah, I was fairly confident that was the right thing to do about this specific question, in hindsight. I'll wait for any discussion on older low quality posts before accepting an answer.